# Workflow form won't appear in Word for a specific computer

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath, word

Environment: SharePoint 2013 On-Premises

We have an approval workflow which is triggered when a user check in a document to a major version. The workflow form is an InfoPath custom form.

Unfortunately, one specific user won't get to see the InfoPath form when in Word (and the workflow doesn't start at all). He is the only known user to have this issue.

Some testing revealed that its user account is not the issue as the same account is working fine on my PC. Furthermore, the InfoPath form will be shown if checking in from the SharePoint Library in Explorer. Both PC have Word 2013.

It looks like there is something related to Word which prevents the workflow from being fired / showing the InfoPath form.

I couldn't find anything about this issue, any hint on what could be the cause?

Comment: Is the WebClient Service started on the PC?

Comment: The WebClient Service? The only thing I can tell is that the InfoPath form shows fine in IE, but don't in Word.

Comment: run/open services.msc and look for WebClient
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2012/06/24/enabling-the-webclient-service-in-windows/  This is what shuttles data into the offline MS Office products from the web.

Comment: I'll really have to take a look at this! Thanks for the tip. You can put it as an answer and I'll accept it as soon as I can test it and make it work! Thanks.

Comment: Can the user open the form directly from InfoPath?  Also can the user browse directly to the form in IE?  IE is important because Word can sometimes open an IE instance such as when authenticating to Office 365 before opening a document.

Comment: The user is able to open the InfoPath form from IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try repairing the office installation.  From the Uninstall section of Control Panel, choose repair on your office suite.

Comment: So many searches were done, yet it is this easy... Only by repairing Office, it has, in fact, resolved the issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you install a different version of an office product separate from your suite this can happen.  Like Visio or SPD

Comment: The user had in fact 2 version of Office, which I didn't verified in the first place. I'll try to give this a look first next time!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a similar IE version on both the PC you are testing. Also try to test the same scenario on Google Chrome.

Comment: How could IE or Chrome be causing the issue in Word?

Comment: Where does the infoPath form appear? inside the IE or word?

Comment: The default & InfoPath forms should appears in Word, but only the default "comments" form shows on the pc with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

run/open services.msc and look for WebClient https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnguin/2012/06/24/enabling-the-webclient-service-in-windows/
This is what shuttles data into the offline MS Office products from the web.

Comment: Unfortunatly, its activated, and the issue is still there.